# Setting width of Image in CKEditor 5

Tags: image, ckeditor, width, ckfinder, ckeditor5

I have a page where I use CKEditor 5 with CKFinder 3. 
By default, the images that are included in the textarea are responsive and can only be aligned as `full` or `right`.

The concerning page has photos of contacts on it and they shouldn't be that big. 
How can I configure the width of an image that is inserted through the button of the toolbar?

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#pageTextArea' ), {
        image: {
            styles: [ { name: 'contact', icon: 'right', title: 'My contact style', className: 'my-contact-side-image' } ]
        }
        ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: 'example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
        }
    })

    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide some custom image styling you need to:

First, configure the [image.styles](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_image-ImageConfig.html#member-styles) option.

```
ClassicEditor.create( element, {
     // ...
     image: {
          // ...
          styles: [
              // Pottentially some other style can go here. E.g. the `full` or `side`.
              { name: 'contact', icon: 'right', title: 'My contact style', className: 'my-contact-side-image' }
          ]
     }
}
```

And secondly, make the image 100px wide via CSS:

```
.ck-content figure.image.my-contact-side-image {
      float: right;
      width: 100px;
}
```

Note that you need to handle styles of the created content outside of the editor as well.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.
If I add the image.styles option, the toolbar disappears and the text is shown in code. I adjusted the code above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which toolbar disappears? What text is shown? I've improved the sample, maybe it will help you. Do you have some errors in the console?

Comment: The textarea normally has a ckeditor toolbar. When I configure the image.styles option, the toolbar dissapears, making it just a textarea.
Error I am getting: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
Which refers tot the line where "ckfinder" starts

Comment: class: '...'  should be className: ...
Works great. Thanks.

How do I add a custom icon for this? Is this possible when using CDN?

Comment: Oh. I'll change the code snippet then. Setting a custom icon is described in the https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_image-ImageConfig.html#member-styles.

Comment: I've made a [PR](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/pull/238) to fix it in the docs.